# Is there a better way of writing a function with two async?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I have this function:

```
private async get(iD: string): Promise<Function> {
        return async () => {
            const tallConfig = await longCrudService.getHalf(iD);
            const stream: Stream = tallConfig.stream;

            const response = this.createUrl(tallConfig, stream);
            return response;
        };
    }
```

Is there a way I could re-write this but without using double async, like is there a way I could re-write this by using only the async of the function, and removing the inner async?

Comment: Doesn't seem like the outer function need s to be async at all.

Answer (score 2):

The only decent use of `async` is when you need to `await` directly inside. Since you aren't doing so for the outer function, you can remove it - only the inner function is making use of an `await`.

```
private get(iD: string): Promise <Function> => async () => {
    const tallConfig = await longCrudService.getHalf(iD);
    const stream: Stream = tallConfig.stream;
    const response = this.createUrl(tallConfig, stream);
    return response;
}
```

You could also remove the `async`s entirely if you wanted, in exchange for `.then`.

```
private get(iD: string): Promise <Function> => () => longCrudService.getHalf(iD)
    .then(tallConfig => this.createUrl(tallConfig, tallConfig.stream));
```

Comment: Thanks!, but I'm getting "unreachable code detected", on all other methods in the class, after changing my code to this. Also the arrow in the get method throws this error: "'{' or ';' expected". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for an inner function you can rewrite as such:

```
private async get(iD: string): Promise<Function> {
    const tallConfig = await longCrudService.getHalf(iD);
    const stream: Stream = tallConfig.stream;

    return this.createUrl(tallConfig, stream);
}
```

Make sure that the caller does not need another function call as this would return a promise as specified on your function signature.

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue, the caller is expecting a function. So when I change my code to this, I get the error "Type string is not assignable to type function".

Comment: Can you change the type from `createUrl` to `Function` instead of String ?